# Time in milliseconds to typical time format

Tags: objective-c, xcode, time

I need to convert time collected in milliseconds (e.g. 116124) to typical format of time like this: 03:12:32:04.

I don't know how to simple do it... Could you help me?

Comment: use NSDateFormatter for this.

Comment: You can use NSDateFormatter, but if you're starting with a time duration and not a date you have to do more tricks that it's worth.  The modular division (ie, "remainder") approach described by Fellowsoft is simpler and more straight-forward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to an Apple Dev forum linked here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2350190?start=0&tstart=0

you have to do it yourself. Here is the function you can use that will return a formated string:

```
- (NSString *) formatInterval: (NSTimeInterval) interval{
unsigned long milliseconds = interval;
unsigned long seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
milliseconds %= 1000;
unsigned long minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds %= 60;
unsigned long hours = minutes / 60;
minutes %= 60;

NSMutableString * result = [NSMutableString new];

if(hours)
    [result appendFormat: @"%d:", hours];

[result appendFormat: @"%2d:", minutes];
[result appendFormat: @"%2d:", seconds];
[result appendFormat: @"%2d",milliseconds];

return result;
}
```